# wordpress function.php не работает easing.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

```
 function my_scripts_method() {
            wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
            wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js');
            wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
        }

        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );

        function my_scripts(){
            wp_enqueue_script( 'easingjs', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js', array('jquery'), true, null );

            wp_enqueue_script( 'freelancerjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/freelancer.js', array('easingjs'), true, null );
        }

        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts');
```

Скрипт  'freelancerjs' зависит от 'easingjs', при явном объявлении в футере все хорошо работает, но через правильное объявление в function.php, 'easingjs' не срабатывает и соответственно не работает. jQuery объявлен и с другими скриптами корректно работает, а easing отваливается, консоль молчит, не помогает даже вынос easing в отдельный файл.

код frelancerjs:

// Freelancer Theme JavaScript

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";

 // Start of use strict

    // jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
    $('.page-scroll a').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: ($($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 50)
        }, 1250, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    // Highlight the top nav as scrolling occurs
    $('body').scrollspy({
        target: '.navbar-fixed-top',
        offset: 51
    });

    // Closes the Responsive Menu on Menu Item Click
    $('.navbar-collapse ul li a').click(function(){ 
            $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
    });

    // Offset for Main Navigation
    $('#mainNav').affix({
        offset: {
            top: 100
        }
    })

    // Floating label headings for the contact form
    $(function() {
        $("body").on("input propertychange", ".floating-label-form-group", function(e) {
            $(this).toggleClass("floating-label-form-group-with-value", !!$(e.target).val());
        }).on("focus", ".floating-label-form-group", function() {
            $(this).addClass("floating-label-form-group-with-focus");
        }).on("blur", ".floating-label-form-group", function() {
            $(this).removeClass("floating-label-form-group-with-focus");
        });
    });

})(jQuery); // End of use strict
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".portfolio-grid").each(function(i) {
        $(this).find(".portfolio-link").attr("href", "#portfolioModal_" + i);
        $(this).find(".portfolio-modal").attr("id", "portfolioModal_" + i );
    });

});
```

код easing стандартный (ссылка не минифицированной версии):
 http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.js

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Два последних параметра в wp_enqueue_script заданы странно. Их смысл: (номер версии или false) и (в футере или нет). Непонятно, как WP на такое отреагирует. Поставьте false, true. Т.е. третий = false, четвертый = true.

Comment: даже при правильной расстановке не цепляются скрипты, в инспекторе их просто нет.